# Cookies using Request Response vb.net

Tags: vb.net, cookies, request, response

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 VB.NET on Windows 7 and the WebBrowser Control

What do I have to Imports to make request and response work?

I'm trying to get and set Cookies and all the examples use

```
Response.Cookies.Add 
Request.Cookies("name")
```

I've already done

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
```

My code will not compile.

The suggested replacement is WebRequest and WebResponse, but neither do what I want to do. What do I have to Imports to get Response and Request to work?

Comment: They won't work. The `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` objects are used in a web application to access the current request and response. You don't have a current request and responce in your code, as it's not handling a request. You should look for options to set a cookie outside the scope of a request, not trying to get the `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` objects to work.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that with the web browser control. If you want to read and write cookies you need to write your won asp.net web application.